# Can't git push to Azure anymore

Tags: git, azure

It worked fine yesterday but today when I do a `git push azure master` to a Website in Azure, after entering the password I get this back

```
error: Failed connect to yy.scm.azurewebsites.net:443;
Operation timed out while accessing
https://xx@yy.scm.azurewebsites.net/yy.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Anybody else with this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you connect via SSH?

Comment: I could connect with SSH but I did not try pull-ing. For some reason it just stared working again. I made no changes, just waited 2 hours... I'll accept u r answer @VonC since it was a good tip for trouble-shooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and follow [those advices](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Investigating-issues), including:

#### Make sure the site itself works

> When you run into a git issue, the first thing to try is to hit the site itself (e.g. http://somesite.azurewebsites.net/).
>   If you get some kind of error instead of the default "The web site is under construction" page, then Azure Web Sites are likely down, and nothing related to git will work.

#### Try hitting the root of the git service

> If the main site is up but git is broken in some way, try hitting the root of the Kudu service directly from the browser. This is useful whether you fail to Enable Git, get a failure on the Deployment tab, or get a failure when you git push.
>
> e.g. if your site URL is http://somesite.azurewebsites.net/, the kudu service root URL will be https://somesite.scm.azurewebsites.net/.
>   So use https, and add the scm token. You will be prompted for credentials, which are the same as what you use to 'git push'.

#### If you get an error BEFORE getting prompted for credentials

> That usually means something pretty bad is wrong, causing things to fail before it even reaches the git engine.

#### If you get an error AFTER getting prompted for credentials

> That could mean two different things:
>
> - An issue with Azure Web Sites
> - An issue with the git support itself
>
> Record what the error is and report it to the forum

Comment: My situation falls in the "something pretty bad is wrong" category.  How is that an accepted answer?