# Permissions issues with Azure Websites?

Tags: git, azure, upload, permissions, ftp

Has anyone ever seen a permissions issue with Azure Websites? After the most recent Git deploy (from a user who has deployed many times before) my site just 500s on every page, traces show an access denied problem.

Deploying via git yields:

remote: New deployment received.
remote: Updating branch 'master'.
remote: ....
remote: Updating submodules.
remote: Preparing deployment for commit id '1d9b57677f'.
remote: Preparing files for deployment.
remote: The specified network name is no longer available.
remote: 
remote: Error - Changes committed to remote repository but your website not updated.

Trying to manually redeploy by FTP yields several 'access denied' errors - I can't see any easy way to fix it without contacting azure support??

Any help much appreciated

Best Regards,

Henri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had intermittent issues like this before that seem to simply resolve themselves after a time. Websites is still in preview so it's a bit unstable here and there. Your best bet would be to post a message on the [Git Deployment to Windows Azure forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/azuregit/threads) in case anyone else is having the same issue. If nothing else, David Ebbo reads that :)

Here's a useful set of [troubleshooting tips](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14379981/1859009)